# Prisma ORM as SPARQL client in semantic web

Tags: orm, sparql, prisma, virtuoso

if we add linked data representation in Prisma ORM schemas properly, is it possible to achieve SPARQL functions as with [Virtuoso database](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)?

I am using [nextJS](https://www.prisma.io/nextjs) with [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/) for linked data representation.

Comment: As far as I can tell from a brief perusal of the Prisma and nextJS website, the answer is, "No." Neither Prisma nor nextJS appears to have any support for SPARQL nor RDF, which are both built-in features of Virtuoso. Nor could I find any sign of an ODBC or JDBC driver for Prisma or nextJS, which would make their data available for Virtuoso to expose as Linked Data Views (a/k/a RDF Views).